# Homotopy problem for infinite dimensional topological space III

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, metric-spaces, homotopy-theory, geodesic

This post here is a specification of this [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/139822/homotopy-problem-for-infinite-dimensional-topological-space-ii).

Let $(X_{n},d_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of complete [geodesic metric spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_Riemannian_and_metric_geometry#G) verifying :

- $X_{n}$ is a $n$-dimensional regular [CW complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CW_complex).
- $X_{n}$ is boundaryless and unbounded.
- $X_{n+1}$ is [n-connected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-connected).
- $X_{n} \subset X_{n+1}$
- The distance $d_{n}$ and $d_{n+1}$ generate the same topology on $X_{n}$.
- $\forall x,y \in X_{n}$ : $d_{n+1}(x,y) \le d_{n}(x,y)$.
- $(X_{n},d_{n})$ is [quasi-isometric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-isometry) to $(X_{n+1},d_{n+1})$

**Definition** : Let $d$ be a distance on $ \bigcup{X_{n}}$, defined as follows :   $d(x,y) = lim_{n \to \infty} d_{n}(x,y)$.

**Remark** : There is a small abuse in the previous definition because $d_{n}(x,y)$ is defined only for $x, y \in X_{n}$. But because we take $n \to \infty$, there is no problem.

**Definition** : Let $X:=\overline{\bigcup{X_{n}}}$, the **complete metric space** obtained as a [completion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_space#Completion) of $\bigcup{X_{n}}$ for $d$.

> **Question** : Is $X$ [weakly contractible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakly_contractible) ?

**Remark :** If yes, some of these conditions could be useless for a proof, and others, highly generalized.

Comment: **Regular** (for a CW complex) means that the attaching maps are homeomorphism (see [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/479026/is-a-cw-complex-homeomorphic-to-a-regular-cw-complex)).

Comment: **Boundaryless** (for a regular CW complex) means that the boundary of each closed cell is contained is the union of the boundaries of other closed cells.

Comment: *geodesic* could be a better tag than *geodesy* here and on your similar questions unless you are talking about measuring the Earth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't have to be weakly contractible. The idea of the counter-example is similar as in my previous answer, just some tricks need to be done to satisfy more assumptions.

Fix $d\geq 2$ and take $d$-disks approximating the sphere $S^d$:
$$D_n' = \left\{x\in S^d\ \big|\ x_1\leq 1-\frac{1}{n} \right\} \subseteq \mathbb R^{d+1}.$$
Now let (trick to remove boundary and preserve completeness):
$$D_1=D_1' \times \{0\} \cup \partial D_1'\times [0,\infty) \subseteq \mathbb R^{d+2}\\
D_n = D_{n-1} \cup D_n' \times \{0\} \cup \partial D_n' \times [0,\infty)$$
with natural geodesic metrics. What is going on? For $d=2$ to each circle being a border of some $D_m' \subseteq D_n'$ we glue an infinite cylinder (and analogously in higher dimensions).

Each $D_n$ is contractible and in the limit we get a space that is homotopy equivalent to the sphere $S^d$. So we have the desired counter-example up to a few details. Btw. note that there is no cylinder or interval over the north pole: it's completion with respect to the geodesic metric, not the euclidean metric.

One of the assumptions not satisfied yet is the condition of quasi-isometry. Fortunately we can easily correct it. Attach to the south pole the following set looking like an infinite comb:
$$C=\{x\ |\ x_1=-1 \lor (x_1\leq -1 \land x_2\in \mathbb Z),\ x_3=\ldots=x_{d+2}=0\}.$$
I claim that all our spaces ($X_n=D_n\cup C$) are quasi-isometric with $C$ (with the geodesic metric). In an infinite comb we can always spread the teeth apart to make some free space in the middle - that's where the cylinders go via the quasi-isometry (I skip formal details). Note that the inclusion map is not a quasi-isometry.

Similarly with the dimension assumption - to lower dimension for $n=0$ we can take a discrete net in $C$ as $X_0$ and for $0<n<d$ we can set $X_n=C$. And to increase dimension, we can always take a wedge sum with the $n$-sphere. These changes don't affect other assumptions.

Comment: instead of deleting your answer, do you see a manner for improving it ? But perhaps this time the answer is "yes"... What do you suspect now ?

Comment: I was thinking about fixing $d=2$ and glueing something compact and boundaryless (like the $n$-th projective space) instead of the cylinders. If we have something like van Kampen theorem for higher homotopy groups, it would work: homotopy groups of disk are trivial and the same for low homotopy groups of the projective space - except for the first group, that we kill with the disk.

Comment: By analising the example with the projective spaces I can say, that it may be possible to construct a counterexample by Hurewicz and long exact sequence of homology, if we have a space with trivial middle ($1<i<n$) **homology** groups, just like the middle homotopy groups of projective spaces are trivial... P.S. The projective spaces don't work by the same argument (Hurewicz and long exact sequence).

Comment: P.P.S. The spheres are not OK, because they have trivial fundamental groups and that leads to nontrivial second homology group.

Comment: For information : I have added in the post the assumption "regular" for the CW complexes.

Comment: Actually my counterexample needs spaces that have homology groups of the circle (up to $n-1$), I really doubt if we can found such examples. P.S. You told me about regularity before and the above example is regular.

Comment: You could just ask a question on MSE about such examples ? (Another politics on MSE (MO also) would be to ask questions as less as possible, why ?)